# How do I cancel a friend request on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, friends

If I send a friend request to someone, and after quite some time they haven't accepted, **how do I cancel the friend request?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go to their profile and cancel the friend request.

[image]

Or else, you can use this Google-Crome Extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/elioihkkcdgakfbahdoddophfngopipi to see the list of people who haven't accepted your friend request yet.

Answer (score 12):

After some clicking around I found another way, which wasn't very intuitive:

1. Click on Account -> Edit Friends.
2. Make sure 'All Connections' is highlighted on the left.
3. Search for the person you wish to cancel the friend request with.  He/she should appear in the results with *Friend Request Pending* under his/her name.
4. Click on the X to remove this friend request.  When hovering the mouse above the X, it should have a tooltip of: *Remove Request*
5. A popup should come up to confirm removing the request.  Click Confirm.

Comment: Inconvenient because you have to remember the name of the person (and they might have changed it in their profile), but outside of an app it's about the only way.

Comment: Facebook has removed "All Connections" so this doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to accomplish this.

1. Click *Account* in the upper right.
2. Click *Privacy*.
3. Click *Edit your lists* in the *Block People* section at the bottom.
4. Enter in a name (partial is ok) and click *Block User*.
5. Facebook will bring up a dialog with matches to your search.  Click *Block* for the appropriate user.
6. This will remove the the friend request from the system.  If you wish, you can then unblock the user if you want them to be able to search for you and view your profile according to your privacy settings.

---

1. Click *Account* in the upper right.
2. Click *Edit Friends*
3. Select *All Friends* from the filter

   > [image: recent friends drop down]
4. Click the *X* next to the appropriate user to remove the connection.

#### Notes (for both methods):

If the user in question is online or receives notifications of friend requests, there's nothing you can do about them seeing the request.  If you remove/block them immediately perhaps you can get that done before a notification is sent. But I wouldn't count on that.

Comment: If they have email notifications for facebook friend requests, they will see that the request was sent in their email inbox.

Comment: @Senseful, yes, see my **Notes** section.

Comment: I mean that my guess is that the notification is sent immediately

Comment: @Senseful, Yes, so would I.

Comment: Facebook has removed "All Connections" so the second method doesn't work any more.

Comment: @mark4o I've edited my answer to reflect the new way of doing it to match Facebook's change.  Thanks for drawing attention to the change!

Comment: This question is not about blocking people.

Comment: @RishabhPoddar blocking someone temporarily is one way to cancel a pending friend request.

Comment: yes, it is but it's quite extreme.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Account (top right) -> Edit Friends (or http://www.facebook.com/friends)

Then, on the left side, choose to see All Conections. In that list you'll also see the person you accidentally invited, and remove the friend request.