# Is there a way to see a list of pending friend requests on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to see a list of my pending friend requests on Facebook - that is, a list of people to whom I have sent a friend request, but who have not responded.  I know that status is indicated when I look at a list of friends on account - edit friends - all connections list, but I don't see a way to filter that list by this criterion.

Comment: This is similar to this one here http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3533/how-do-i-cancel-a-friend-request-on-facebook

Comment: @Krampus I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an Application that (for the moment, anyway) will perform this function. It's called, predictably, [Pending Friend Requests](http://apps.facebook.com/friendrequests/).

*[Source](http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=69048030774&topic=7828#post59097)*

Comment: Thanks for adding the fragment to the link, Senseful. I didn't have any idea how to find that (short of viewing source, and I was short on time).

Comment: The app is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

There a loophole to see pending friend requests on Facebook Timeline. Although Facebook does show you with all the friend requests received, there is no direct means to access the request you have sent from your account. But you can still keep track of them using the Facebook’s “[***Download Your Information***](http://www.sociobits.org/2013/04/view-your-pending-friend-requests-on-facebook-timeline-may-2013.html)” option. Follow:

1. Go to your '**Account Settings**'
2. Click on '**Download a Copy of your Facebook data**' on bottom of page.
3. Select '**expanded archive**' from the link below.
4. After entering your Password, click on '**Start My Archive**'
5. Once the archive is ready, you will receive an email. Now you need to **download** the archive from the link. (Usually takes 1 to 2 hours)
6. Extract downloaded zip file and Open **index.html**
7. Then navigate to “**Pending friend requests**” link. Click that link, now you can see the whole pending friend requests list on 'Pending Sent Friend Requests' head. It will also shows you the 'Pending Received Friend Requests'. You can also view friends whom you have deleted from your account.

You're done! c: